# ¿Por qué los chats están en Stack Exchange y no en Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange, chat

El chat de *Stack Overflow en español* se aloja en **stackexchange.com** en vez de **stackoverflow.com**

El enlace de los chats hacia *Stack Overflow en español* es el siguiente:

- `https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com`

Como se puede ver, se está escribiendo dos enlaces en un solo enlace, estando alojado en *Stack Exchange*.

Esto se ve diferente si se mueve a una de las siguientes direcciones:

- `https://chat.es.stackoverflow.com`
- `https://es.chat.stackoverflow.com`

¿Esto se discutió en algún momento? ¿Estaría bien mover todo a *Stack Overflow*?

Se me ocurre que en vez de moverlo se podría congelar el chat y empezar una sala nueva desde cero en **es.chat.stackoverflow.com**. De esta manera cualquier vinculación al chat anterior seguiría siendo válida.

Además de esto, ¿Sería apropiado crear una interfaz en español del chat? Por ejemplo, que en vez de **Upload** diga **Subir imagen**, y que permita buscar mensajes con caracteres especiales, por ejemplo la **ñ** o tildes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En cuanto a la primera cuestión, Stack Overflow es sitio mas grande de la red Stack Exchange con muchísima diferencia y tiene numerosos chats activos. Supongo que por eso se decidió en un principio que todos los demás chats estarían en StackExchange, aunque no puedo asegurarlo.

Personalmente veo que trasladar el chat a otro dominio tiene pocas ventajas (¿ninguna?) y si inconvenientes dado que la mayoría de usuarios ya saben donde está el chat actualmente y cambiarlo podría suponer un inconveniente para ellos.

En cuanto a cambiar el idioma...no se si ni siquiera es factible. Debes tener en cuenta que el chat es común para todos los sitios y probablemente no sea posible personalizarlo para un chat en concreto. Además, Stack Exchange ha dejado claro en numerosas ocasiones que el chat no es una prioridad para ellos, no creo que estén por la labor de meter recursos para modificar nada.

---

He preguntado de todas maneras sobre el tema y esto me ha respondido un CM (traduzco):

> No se puede mover, no. Son diferentes.Son bases de datos completamente
>   separadas y tratar de mover el contenido de una a otra podría... matar
>   todo.
>
> En cuanto a por qué, supongo que
>   desde que pasaron por el proceso beta, fueron considerados sitios SE
>   originalmente... Ya no los consideramos SE - se supone que tienen
>   prioridad como SO - pero el servidor de chat (probablemente) no va a
>   cambiar... y si lo cambiáramos, probablemente requeriría abandonar
>   todo el contenido antiguo. Migrarlo a chat.so sería imposible.
>
> En cuanto a la traducción de la interfaz de usuario... ...no tengo ni
>   idea. Supongo que si fuera posible, lo habríamos hecho... Puedo
>   preguntar... o pueden poner una pregunta en MSE sobre ello.